# htacces on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, apache2

I have an issue with getting .htaccess running on apache in Ubuntu. I tried a lot but nothing helps. I don't know how to fix that.

Conf file snippet /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/demo.conf

```
    <Directory /var/www/demo/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Conf file snippet from /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

and

```
    AccessFileName .htaccess
```

Part of the .htaccess wher I try to remove file suffix.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Make sure You have module `rewrite_module` enabled. Run `apache2ctl -M`. If not - enable it by `a2enmod rewrite`.

Comment: Hey, sure I did. I just forgot to mention it. ```apache2ctl -M |grep rewrite
 rewrite_module (shared)```